# How to determine Series Convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{n^3}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(n+l)}}$$

Determine all positive integer 'l' such that the following series converges and if it converges, compute its value. How can I solve it?

Comment: $l \in \{5,6,\cdots\}$. Now do your work yourself.

Comment: The sum of $1/n$ does not converge while $1/n^2$ does.

Comment: For values l = 5,6,7,... The series converges; The value of convergence for l = 5 the least of l = $\frac{25}{288}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
{n^{3} \over \pars{n + 1}\pars{n + 2}\pars{n + 3}\ldots\pars{n + \ell}}}$. The general series term goes $\sim 1/n^{\ell - 3}$ when $n \gg 1$ which indicates that the series converges for $\ds{\large\quad\ell \geq 5\,,\quad\ell \in {\mathbb N}}$.

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#00f}{\large\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
> {n^{3} \over \pars{n + 1}\pars{n + 2}\pars{n + 3}\ldots\pars{n + \ell}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{3}\,{n! \over \pars{n + \ell}!}
> ={1 \over \pars{\ell - 1}!}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
> n^{3}\,{\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\Gamma\pars{\ell} \over \Gamma\pars{n + \ell + 1}}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over \pars{\ell - 1}!}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{3}
> \int_{0}^{1}t^{n}\pars{1 - t}^{\ell - 1}\,\dd t
> ={1 \over \pars{\ell - 1}!}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}^{\ell - 1}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{3}t^{n}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over \pars{\ell - 1}!}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}^{\ell - 1}\,
> {t\pars{1 + 4t + t^{2}} \over \pars{1 - t}^{4}}\,\dd t
> ={1 \over \pars{\ell - 1}!}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{t + 4t^{2} + t^{3}}
> \pars{1 - t}^{\ell - 5}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over \pars{\ell - 1}!}\bracks{%
> {\Gamma\pars{2}\Gamma\pars{\ell - 4} \over \Gamma\pars{\ell -2}}
> +4\,{\Gamma\pars{3}\Gamma\pars{\ell - 4} \over \Gamma\pars{\ell - 1}}
> + {\Gamma\pars{4}\Gamma\pars{\ell - 4} \over \Gamma\pars{\ell}}}
> \\[3mm]&={\pars{\ell - 5}! \over \pars{\ell - 1}!}\bracks{%
> {1 \over \pars{\ell - 3}!} + {8 \over \pars{\ell - 2}!} +{6 \over \pars{\ell - 1}!}}
> \\[3mm]&={\pars{\ell - 5}! \over \pars{\ell - 1}!}\,{1 \over \pars{\ell - 3}!}
> \bracks{%
> 1 + 8\,{\pars{l - 3}! \over \pars{\ell - 2}!} + 6\,{\pars{l - 3}! \over \pars{\ell - 1}!}}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over \pars{\ell - 3}\pars{\ell - 4}\pars{\ell - 1}!}\,
> \bracks{%
> 1 + {8 \over \pars{\ell - 2}} + {6 \over \pars{\ell - 1}\pars{\ell - 2}}}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over \pars{\ell -3}\pars{\ell - 4}\pars{\ell - 1}!}\,
> {\ell^{2} - 3\ell + 2 + 8\ell - 8 + 6 \over \pars{\ell - 1}\pars{\ell - 2}}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large{1 \over \pars{\ell - 1}!}\,
> {\ell\pars{\ell + 5} \over
>  \pars{\ell - 1}\pars{\ell - 2}\pars{\ell - 3}\pars{\ell - 4}}\,,
> \qquad \ell \in {\mathbb N}\,,\quad \ell \geq 5}
> \end{align}